# How do I add I18n locale dictionaries from gem to Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a gem that makes use of I18n locale dictionaries that reside in lib/locales/*.yml inside my gems folder.

When the gem is initialized I want to load these dictionaries into my rails application, but I cannot figure out how:

This is what I tried:

```
I18n.load_path += Dir.glob("lib/locales/*.{rb,yml}")
```

Unfortunately this does not work when the gem is loaded inside my Rails App. When I call `I18n.t("foo")` I get `"translation missing: en, foo"`.

I will probably have to provide the full path to the locales when invoking I18n.load_path, but I cannot figure out how.

Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `__FILE__`

```
Dir.glob( File.dirname(__FILE__) + "lib/locales/*.{rb,yml}" )
```

Comment: Yeah, that works! I figured it out in the meanwhile, as so often when writing down a question ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Despite being an eleven year old post this is still applicable today

Answer (score 3):

For the record, if you put your locales in `<GEM_ROOT>/config/locales`, they will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Only if the gem is a Rails Engine