# How to internationalize a a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, internationalization, rubygems, i18n-gem

What is the best way to ship a gem with default i18n translations for strings used by it?

Comment: If it still interests you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392425/how-do-i-add-i18n-locale-dictionaries-from-gem-to-rails-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do :

- include `i18n` as a dependency
- internationalize your gem by replacing strings with `I18n.t` calls
- create a translation YAML file and add it to I18n's `load_path` (e.g. `I18n.load_path += 'path/to/your/en.yml'` )

That's pretty much it, you can also set up a [public project on Locale](http://www.localeapp.com/projects/public) to crowdsource translations in other locales if you're so inclined.

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean? Do you have a project you want to internationalize?
you might want to look at the [i18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n). But it is really no big deal to roll your own, as I did here for example: [notebot](https://github.com/robbiemu/notebot).

Comment: I have a gem that I want to internationalize.

Comment: strange to be voted down for an answer that is basically identical to the one above mine that was voted up